# ComboxBox display text not correct

Tags: wpf, combobox

I have this code :

```
<ComboBox
   SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" 
   x:Name="TeamList" 
   Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxTeamInput}" 
   ItemsSource="{Binding Teams}"  
   DisplayMemberPath="TeamName" 
   SelectedValuePath="TeamId" 
   Template="{DynamicResource ComboBoxControlTemplate1}" />
```

The items inside the popup menu are correctly displayed. But on selecting the item, it selects the correct item but the value displayed is somewhat like 'System.Data.Entity.....'.
This problem occurred after I changed the `ControlTemplate` of `ComboBox`. In control template, I only change the background color.\

My ControlTemplate looks like this:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">

            <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" Width="0"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
                    <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="shadow" Color="Transparent" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=templateRoot}">
                        <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                                <Grid x:Name="grid" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                    <Canvas x:Name="canvas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=DropDownBorder}"/>
                                    </Canvas>
                                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
                </Popup>
                <ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                    <ToggleButton.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
                            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
                            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                            <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press"/>
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">

                                        <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="#FFACACAC" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                            <Border.Background>
                                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                                            </Border.Background>
                                            <Border x:Name="splitBorder" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}">
                                                <Path x:Name="Arrow" Data="F1M0,0L2.667,2.66665 5.3334,0 5.3334,-1.78168 2.6667,0.88501 0,-1.78168 0,0z" Fill="#FF606060" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                            </Border>
                                        </Border>
                                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="White"/>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FFABADB3"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="Transparent"/>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="Transparent"/>
                                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="Black"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="false"/>
                                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFECF4FC" Offset="0"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFDCECFC" Offset="1"/>
                                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                </Setter>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF7EB4EA"/>
                                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="White"/>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF7EB4EA"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFEBF4FC" Offset="0"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFDCECFC" Offset="1"/>
                                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                </Setter>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="#FF7EB4EA"/>
                                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="Black"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="false"/>
                                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFDAECFC" Offset="0"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFC4E0FC" Offset="1"/>
                                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                </Setter>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF569DE5"/>
                                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="White"/>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF569DE5"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFDAEBFC" Offset="0"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFC4E0FC" Offset="1"/>
                                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                </Setter>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="#FF569DE5"/>
                                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="#FFBFBFBF"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="false"/>
                                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FFF0F0F0"/>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FFD9D9D9"/>
                                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="White"/>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FFBFBFBF"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="Transparent"/>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="Transparent"/>
                                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </ToggleButton.Style>
                </ToggleButton>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="shadow" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
                    <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="shadow" Value="#71000000"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="DropDownBorder" Value="95"/>
                </Trigger>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="True"/>
                        <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="False"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="False"/>
                </MultiTrigger>
                <Trigger Property="CanContentScroll" SourceName="DropDownScrollViewer" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

Its the generated one, I've just changed the background. Where should I specify the Label thing?

Comment: Can you supply the ControlTemplate?

Answer (score 0):

Your new template doesn't now what property do display from the SelectedItem, so it just calls that objects .ToString() method.
Add to control template property you wich value you wish to display

Something like this

```
    <ControlTemplate>
                <Label Content="{Binding PropertyToDisplay}"/>
   </ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the dynamic template cannot be found and therefore the entry is only presented in its simplest form (WPF Fallback) as a label showing the ToSTring() output of your items... Take a look if the Resource can be found...